# using mysql in latex

Tags: mysql, sql, latex

I have a mysql database that contains snippets of latex code, identified by a unique id which I imaginatively called id.

Now I would like to typeset a document with latex in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dbquery}[1]{???}
\begin{document}
Some text \dbquery{23} some more text etc.
\end{document}
```

So the idea is, whenever the macro \dbquery appears, the latex code with id=23 in the db is inserted into the text.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have more luck at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This can be done from within LaTeX using [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool), if your database is stored as a CSV file.

Comment: This is a latex question and should be linked to:
[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-database-to-latex-to-produce-data-driven-documents][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-database-to-latex-to-produce-data-driven-documents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at [LaTeXDB](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexdb). Since it connects LaTeX to a MySQL database, it should be your friend here.